# Trying to catch error when writing to socket using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm attempting to create a try/catch when I send a message to a socket (IRC server, Twitch specifically)

Mine is constantly sending messages to the socket. At one point, the other party (in this case Twitch) will end the connection. I need to catch that error and then reconnect

I have this code. the try and catch does not work

```
Bot.irc = new tls.TLSSocket()

Bot.irc.connect({
    host: 'irc.chat.twitch.tv',
    port: this.port
  })

Bot.writeIrcMessage = (msg) => {
    console.log('writing irc msg > ', msg)

    try {
        Bot.irc.write(msg + "\r\n")
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('error writing irc message: ', e)
    }
}
```

And this is the error from my console

```
writing irc msg >  JOIN #twitchusername
{ Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at TLSSocket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:356:12)
    at TwitchBot.Bot.writeIrcMessage (/home/node/chatbot/libs/bot.js:22:17)
    at TwitchBot.join (/home/node/chatbot/node_modules/twitch-bot/lib/bot.js:145:10)
    at /home/node/chatbot/libs/bot.js:101:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.join (/home/node/chatbot/libs/bot.js:92:37)
    at _callee2$ (/home/node/chatbot/libs/messagequeue.js:87:17)
    at tryCatch (/home/node/chatbot/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/home/node/chatbot/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/home/node/chatbot/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21) code: 'EPIPE' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is not captured because of the inherent asynchronous nature of nodejs sockets.

So, if the api does not provide a callback (like .write(msg, function ack(error) {})) you could use ES6 Promises. A generic example:

```
const myFunc = function () {
  return doSomething()
    .then(a => {
      return Promise.all([a, doSomethingelse()])
    })
}
```

More examples at https://runnable.com/blog/handling-errors-with-es6.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `error` or the `end` message:

```
Bot.irc.on('error', msg => { 
    // Handle the error, e.g., by reconnecting.
});
Bot.irc.on('end', msg => {
    // Can't write to a socket that ended. 
});
```